# Cocoa pod issue

Tags: objective-c, github, cocoapods

I have setup my library cocoa pod setup and set it on git now i am trying to install it with pod but it gives me following error

```
Unable to find a specification for ‘pod name’
```

any one have any idea about this error and why pod not install.

Comment: Show me your podfile

Comment: is -(dash) allow in pod name like podname-ios?Actually i have create own library pod and setup on git and now try to install it with pod file for that do we need to set anything on git?

Comment: It looks like you have incorrect podfile setup. Post your Podfile and lets find out the issue.

Comment: issue is resolve i have not register my lib with trunk in cocoapod i done that and it works fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check in your Podfile for the target, `target` should be same to your `project name`

**Sample**

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'

target "Project name" do //check here "Project name" should be same to your project name
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
end
```

Comment: is -(dash) allow in pod name like podname-ios?Actually i have create own library pod and setup on git and now try to install it with pod file for that do we need to set anything on git?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have problems setting up your Specs，Likely same issue to https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6444
The solution is as follows, enter the following command in the terminal:

1. `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods`
2. `pod setup`
3. After successful execution, `pod install` or `pod update`

Comment: i have tried this `pod repo remove master
pod setup` but still it is not working.

Comment: @HardikA i think had better 'rm -rf ~/.cocoapods'   then 'pod setup' again ; if u do not have Authorization，use 'sudo rm -rf ~/.cocoapods' then 'pod setup'

Comment: Actually i have create own library pod and setup on git and now try to install it with pod file for that do we need to set anything on git? i am trying for ur above solution.

Comment: @HardikA ohoh,now i understand,1,in terminal try pod search your own library , if has result , add the library in your own podfile ,if not find try pod set up ，then pod search again, if still not find open ~/.cocoapds look your spec structure，to look if has your own library outside the folder，if have delete it , than repeat pod setup 、search again